# Grid view in MFC

Tags: c++, gridview, user-interface, mfc, tabular

I've to create an application which is made up in a tabular way, with rows and columns having cells, in a grid like format. There have to be appropriate cell-level controls as well.

Because of certain constraints, this has to be done in MFC.

I tried searching for something like Grid view/tabular view in MFC, but couldn't locate it. All I managed to get were user developed libraries on other sites, but which I cannot use because of license restrictions.

As a starting point, what should I be looking for? I've worked on Qt before, but not MFC, and am fining it difficult to locate appropriate tutorials regarding grid/tabular view.

Kindly give me a starting point, or a library name for me to start looking into.

Thanks.

Comment: If you need to display tabular data within a simple MFC dialog, a CListCtrl is usually sufficient, however a more complex Excel-like program will likely require you to create your own way of doing this.

Comment: For a solution that easily integrates into MFC you may want to look into [The Ultimate Grid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20183/The-Ultimate-Grid-Home-Page). It is a bit dated, but still quite powerful. The license is fairly open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you use something open source like the ultimate grid or CGridCtrl, or you use a library like BCGSuite. You say 'cannot use because of licence restrictions' but you don't say what you mean. CGridCtrl for example can be used in commercial and free applications. For a high-quality (i.e., with support for modern features like theming), you'll need a commercial library.